# Android Google map to provide alternative route

Tags: google-maps

Google Map web version can provide 3 alternative routes when routing directions. However, it seems Android Google map can only provide 1 route and have no option to choose alternative routes. Is there any way to get the alternative routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see alternate routes, you need to use Navigation as opposed to Maps.

If you already have Maps open, click the blue arrowhead in the upper right to switch to Navigation, then click the context button on your phone, then select `Route Info`, then click the third button to the right along the bottom which will have both a dashed and solid line going to a map pin.  Alternate routes will appear, and you can select them along the top of the route info map.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that in navigation mode the routes displayed are from the current location and not between the two locations selected.